# A sequence of Hilbert spaces and a sequence of linear funtionals

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $\{h_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset H$ be a sequence of linearly independent vectors in $H$

Let $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: H_m = \overline{\operatorname{span}}\{h_p\}_{p \geq m}$ and we know that $h_m \notin H_{m+1}$

We have $h_m \to h_0$ in norm convergence

Let $f \in H^*$ be a bounded linear functional on $H$ and we know that $f(h_0)=0$

Let $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: f_m = f \mid _{H_m}$ be the restriction of $f$ to $H_m$

My question is: is it true that $$ \left\| f_m \right\| \to 0$$

Thanks.

Comment: The only relevant information is  that $(H_n)_n$ is a nested sequence of closed spaces with $\cap_n H_n=(0)$, which implies that the orthogonal projectors $P_m$ converge strongly to $0$, that is $\|P_mf\|=\|f_m\|\to0$ (identifying $f$ with an element of $H$)

Comment: @PietroMajer , why you say that $\bigcap_nH_n=\{0\}$ ? We have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: h_0 \in H_n$ so $h_0 \in \bigcap_nH_n$

Comment: I added a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Even without the conditions $h_n\to h_0$ and $f(h_0)=0$.

So let's assume that $H_n$ is a sequence of subspaces such that $\bigcap_nH_n=\{0\}$, $H_{n+1}\subset H_n$ and $\dim(H_n/H_{n+1})=1$ for each $n$.
Let $e_n\in H_n$ be a norm 1 vector which is orthogonal to $H_{n+1}$.
Let $x_n=f(e_n)$. By the boundedness of $f$ it follows that $\sum_n|x_n|^2<\infty$. Further, by Riesz theorem we have $\left\|f_m\right\|^2=\sum_{j\ge m}|x_j|^2$. This tends to zero.

EDIT: Pu to this point, I did not exactly answer the question, I proved something different. Indeed, one cannot assume $\bigcap_nH_n=0$.
Here is a counterexample:

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space and let $(e_j)_{j\ge 0}$ be an orthonormal basis.
Set 
$$
h_n=\frac1n\big(e_0+e_n\big).
$$
Then $h_n\to 0$.
For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $H_n$ be the closure of the span of $h_m$, $m\ge n$ and let $f_n=nh_n=e_0+e_n\in H_n$.
For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $k(n)\in\mathbb N$ be the largest natural number such that
$$
\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\dots+\frac1{k(n)-1}\le 1.
$$
For $j=n,n+1,\dots,k(n)-1$ let $\lambda^{(n)}_j=\frac1j$ and let $\lambda^{(n)}_{k(n)}$ be the unique rational number $0\le \lambda^{(n)}_{k(n)}\le \frac1{k(n)}$ such that
$$
\lambda^{(n)}_n+\dots+\lambda_{k(n)}^{(n)}=1.
$$
Let 
$$
v_n=\lambda^{(n)}_nf_n+\dots+\lambda^{(n)}_{k(n)}f_{k(n)}= e_0+\lambda_n^{(n)}e_n+\dots\lambda^{(n)}_{k(n)}e_{k(n)}.
$$
Then $v_n$ lies in $H_n$ and as
$$
|\lambda_n^{(n)}|^2+\dots+|\lambda_{k(n)}^{(n)}|^2\le \frac1{n^2}+\dots+\frac1{k(n)^2}
$$
tends to zero, we conclude $v_n\to e_0$.
Hence $e_0$ lies in $H_n$ and so it lies in $\bigcap_nH_n$.
Then the linear functional $f:H\to\mathbb C$, defined by $f\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_ne_n\right)=c_0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thaks @Zero for your answer

Comment: Why $\bigcap_nH_n=\{0\}$ ? Please can you give me a proof ? @Zero

Comment: why you assume that $H_n$ is a sequence of subspaces such that $\bigcap_nH_n=\{0\}$, $H_{n+1}\subset H_n$ and $\dim(H_n/H_{n+1})=1$ for each $n$ @Zero

Comment: I added a counterexample.